# Default function in Python using min

Tags: python, function, min

For my problem I have to write a min function that can take up to 4 numeric arguments but must have at least 2. The third and fourth arguments have to be set to None if they aren't passed a value. The function should return the smallest value of those passed and must work with either 2, 3, or 4 values.
This is what I have:

```
def min(num1, num2, num3=None, num4=None):
   if num1<num2:
     result=num1
   elif num2<num1:
     result=num2
   elif num3>None:
     if num3<num1 and num3<num2:
       result=num3
   else:
     min_num=num4
   return result
```

When I run it in python and enter 4 values, it doesn't return the minimum number. It just returns a random number from the four arguments I entered. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So you just need to return the smallest value of the (up to) 4 numbers?

Comment: Yes, I just need to return the smallest value of up to 4 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `elif` which only executes if `if` condition is false. So, you can fix by using all `if` conditions. Also, you have default value to `None` which you can compare using `!= None`. You can try something like:

```py
def minimum(num1, num2, num3=None, num4=None):
    # this first  if else will check with num1 and num2 only  
    if num1 < num2:
        result = num1
    else:
        result = num2

    # after checking between num1 and num2
    # the result will be checked with num3
    # if num3 is provided
    if num3 is not None and num3 < result:
        result = num3

    # if num4 also provided then the result will be compared with it
    if num4 is not None and num4 < result:
        result = num4
    return result
```

Comment: It's better to check for None using `is`, rather than `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed in several ways.  Draw the logic tree your want, the way *you* would do it with a list of numbers, and implement *that*, rather than what you've posted here.

```
   if num1<num2:
      result=num1
   elif num2<num1:
      result=num2
   elif ...
```

Look at the logic here: the only way you get to the last two arguments is if num1 == num2.  If you feed your function `(5, 7, 1, 0)`, it will return 5.

```
   elif num3>None:
```

What are you trying to do here?  `None` is not a valid numerical value; this is an illegal comparison.  Try

```
    if num3 is not None and ...
```

Suggested logic: keep track of the smallest number so far in a separate variable; compare each value against *that*.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution in order to avoid the ifs and using an in-built function.

```
def my_min(num1, num2, num3=None, num4=None):
  my_numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4]
  return min(my_numbers)


print(my_min(4, 3, 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use the `min()` as your function name, because it is a keyword of python.

Secondly, the number of "if-else" conditions should be minimal, it is too much, you might need to think about other options.

```
def custom_min(num1, num2, num3=None, num4=None):
    min_value = num1
    for num in [num2, num3, num4]:
        if !(num is None) and min_value>num:
            min_value = num
    return min_value

print(custom_min(1, 2))
print(custom_min(2, 1, 4))
print(custom_min(2, 1, 4, 0))
```

The output is:

```
1
1
0
```

Comment: It's better to check for None using `is`, rather than `==`.